# How to Use Memcache with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, memcached

I have web application of which major part is javascript.

I request images from the disk and rendered on the UI, it is a kind of ebook reader application. For every page of ebook I have corresponding image saved on the disk.

No my application has performance hit, it has very high disk io specifically disk read operation. To improve disk read operation, I am planning to use memcache.

So now i wanted to use memcache with by javascript calls to fetch images from memcache rather from disk. Guide me through this...

Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand... why a negative vote for this question... Do mention the reason also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your javascript is being used at browser-side, then you have to write some http server-side code to wrap image getting operation. Modifying only javascript code will do nothing.

For example, originally you request `http://example.com/ebook1/page1.jpg`, you should change it to `http://example.com/ebook1/get_page.php?page=1`(suppose you implement it in php), and use memcache inside that php.

For server-side js, there are several memcache lib built on node.js

Comment: URL changes are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, but not-changing url requires some configuration modification in the web server side, which is a little bit more complicated than using a wrapper directly.

Comment: @CAFxX... as I mention to reduce diskIO.. request for images are very frequest.. so in this case DiskIO is performance hit.. that's y I am planning to use memcache